# PHP trying to split paragraph into sentences. Keep punctuation

Tags: php, regex

Basically I'm taking in a paragraph filled with all kinds of punctuation
such as ! ? . ; " and splitting them into sentences. 
The issues I'm facing is coming up with a way to split them into sentences with punctuation intact while at the same time accounting for quotations in dialogue

For instance the paragraph:

> One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found
>   himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. "What has
>   happened!?" he asked himself. "I... don't know." said Samsa, "Maybe
>   this is a bad dream." He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted
>   his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and
>   divided by arches into stiff sections.

Would need to be split up like this

```
[0] One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. 

[1] "What has happened!?" he asked himself.

[2] "I... don't know." said Samsa, "Maybe this is a bad dream."
```

And so on.

Currently I am just using explode

```
$sentences = explode(".", $sourceWork);
```

and only splitting it up by the periods and appending one at the end. Which I know is far from what I want but I'm not quite sure where to even start handling this. If someone could at least point me the right direction of where to look for ideas that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Yesterday I've been to Mt. Rushmore."

Comment: @Ozerich: yes, pretty much impossible to parse natural language accurately. The more you try, the more you'll find examples that don't fit the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I have:

```
<?php

/**
 * @param string $str                          String to split
 * @param string $end_of_sentence_characters   Characters which represent the end of the sentence. Should be a string with no spaces (".,!?")
 *
 * @return array
 */
function split_sentences($str, $end_of_sentence_characters) {
    $inside_quotes = false;
    $buffer = "";
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $buffer .= $str[$i];
        if ($str[$i] === '"') {
            $inside_quotes = !$inside_quotes;
        }
        if (!$inside_quotes) {
            if (preg_match("/[$end_of_sentence_characters]/", $str[$i])) {
                $result[] = $buffer;
                $buffer = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$str = <<<STR
One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. "What has happened!?" he asked himself. "I... don't know." said Samsa, "Maybe this is a bad dream." He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections.
STR;

var_dump(split_sentences($str, "."));
```

Comment: @Ozerich: It's impossible to differentiate every single detail in the English language. How would you detect whether it's an end of sentance or not? "If it has a Mr or Mrs before it it's not an end). But then there's Dr. that you've forgotten, and Prof.. There's no end to it. You'll just have to find that spot where you compromise, and move on.

Comment: Yes, i know that it's impossible, and it means that your solution, as my solution aren't ready for production :)

Comment: @Ozerich: OP asked for something to exclude the punctuation marks inside of quotes, that's what I gave him. I'm pretty certain that what he had before was worse (since things in quotes would not be spared), hence, this solution works for the OP needs. The OP should be aware of the simple limitation of English (not PHP) which can spawn a period in unexpected places. That is not a PHP problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_split('/[.?!]/',$sourceWork);
```

it's very simple regular expression, but i think you task is impossible.

Comment: `[2] "I... don't know." said Samsa, "Maybe this is a bad dream."` - will it work whit this? `...`

Comment: I could do that. But the only issue with that is that it wouldn't account for punctuation in dialogue. I'd get stuck with random quotation marks beginning sentences.

Answer (score 0):

you need to manually go through your String and do explodes. Keep track of quotation count, if it is odd number do not break, here is a simple idea:

```
    <?
//$str = 'AAA. BBB. "CCC." DDD. EEE. "FFF. GGG. HHH".';
$str = 'One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. "What has happened!?" he asked himself. "I... don\'t know." said Samsa, "Maybe this is a bad dream." He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections.';
$last_dot=0;
$quotation=0;
$explode_list = Array();
for($i=0;$i < strlen($str);$i++)
{
    $char = substr($str,$i,1);//get the currect character
    if($char == '"') $quotation++;//track quotation
    if($quotation%2==1) continue;//nothing to do so go back

    if($char == '.')
    {
        echo "char is $char $last_dot<br/>";
         $explode_list[]=(substr($str,$last_dot,$i+1-$last_dot));
         $last_dot = $i+1;
    }
}

echo "testing:<pre>";
print_r($explode_list);;
```

Comment: Not sure what this is, but it's not PHP.

Comment: I have fixed the code to run this time, you can see an example here: http://farzad.devbro.com/break_string.php